# Change environment path into the makefile with MinGW32-make.exe on Windows

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw, mingw-w64

I have a makefile that I want to compile a DLL with MinGW on Windows.

This project I want to compile into 32 & 64 bits.

I have MinGW32 installed into `C:\MinGW32` with the x86 compiler and `C:\MinGW64` with the x64 compiler.

The makefile, uses one or another path depending of the target, but the problem I have is that I need to specify `C:\MinGWxx\bin` on global environvment path, because it needs some of the DLLs of the bin directory.

I tried some solutions like 
[Specifying path in makefile (GNU make on Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258851/specifying-path-in-makefile-gnu-make-on-windows), but it doesn't work.

It seems that exports is not reconogized in this version of operating system (or not supported for make).

I tried to put

```
SET Path=$(PATH_DVL_x86)\bin;$(PATH_DVL_x86)\msys\1.0\bin;${PATH}
```

This doesn't return error, but no changes on environment path.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use the [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) special target to force the recipes to run all commands in one shell:

```
.ONESHELL:

.PHONY: all anotherRule

all:
    @ECHO OFF
    ECHO %PATH% # Will echo your PATH environment variable content
    SET PATH=%PATH%;toto
    ECHO %PATH% # Will echo your PATH + ";toto" appended to it

anotherRule:
    @ECHO OFF
    ECHO %PATH% # Will echo your PATH without ";toto", as expected
```

Now it is easy to write specific rules to use with different compilers:

```
all-x86: CC := mingw32-gcc
all-x86: ...
    ...

all-64: CC := mingw64-gcc
all-64: ...
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, super-helpful, this! Thanks for taking the time to record it. By including the `.ONESHELL` target, I was *finally* able to set the path for a required `TMPDIR` environment variable from within the Makefile I use to compile R from sources on Windows. Following `ONESHELL:`, I did `export "TMPDIR:=C:\tmp"`, and all was good.